Papers including non open-source code and not including non open-source code?
My question is very specific. I read papers/books that in order for the author to build the system, they need to program the hardware in IP protected code. Some papers or books publish the code. However the  majority of papers/books I read, do not include the IP protected code. My question is very simple, how can this happen? I am not talking about open-source programming languages. What is the rationale behind that? Who decides if the authors can publish their code or not? (There is no need to specify companies, that's why I put my question in a more general shape).

Are you asking "Why is some code IP-protected?" or "Why would a journal permit a paper to be published that didn't include code?" or something else?

It's unclear to me what you're asking. Are you asking about the copyright on software which the authors of a paper wrote themselves, or about the copyright status of programming languages?

About the copyright status of programming languages. There are programming languages which are not open-source.

I am asking the way an author can publish in their book code that they wrote, but are based on non open-source programming language. How can they do that?

@mike: Maybe something like ‘my code was deployed using AWS Lambda’ or ‘this custom system makes use of an Oracle backend.’

The title "Papers including X and papers not including X?" can be simplified to "Papers?".

A programming language (PL) is a tool. Things created with that tool are not owned by the creator of the language. Nor does Microsoft own everything written in Word. IP is owned by its creators (in a sense). That "ownership" might be limited by law, of course. So, if I write a program in a PL, I have copyright to that code and can publish it or not. The creator of that PL has no claim on my creative work, just as I have no claim on theirs.
There would be little purpose in creating a programming language and making it public if people couldn't use it to create things that might be monetized or published. A company could, of course, create a PL and keep it as a trade secret.
Imagine a world in which things published (PLs and papers) can't be used by others because they are automatically the IP of the creators of the tools used to create them.
A publisher of a PL can hold copyright to the compiler(s) they release for that language, which restricts some things, but not using it to create things. And, the ideas behind the code are not "owned" by anyone. Laws such as copyright and patent apply to "expressions" and "devices", not ideas. So the idea of a class (as in Java or C++) is free for anyone to use.
And so, it is the authors of the code who decide whether to publish it or not. There might be reasons for either decision.
